# What is the state after entangled qubit transfer?

Tags: entanglement, measurement

Suppose Alice has 2 qubit entangled state and wants to send 1st qubit to Bob.

q1) Now what is left with Alice? Both 1st and 2nd qubits or only 2nd qubit?
q2) Does the overall composite quantum system be in the same entangled state as with Alice initially?

Answer (score 1):

As for **Q1:** - Presumably you mean she "sends" her first qubit to Bob by teleporting it  to Bob.  By the no-cloning theorem, if Alice sends her first qubit to Bob, she cannot have possession of both the first qubit and the second qubit.  She only has possession of the second qubit.

As for **Q2:** - After teleportation, the overall composite system is in the same entangled state.  A difference is presumably that if Alice had possession of both qubits initially she could have performed controlled operations on the qubits (e.g. the first qubit can control a rotation of the second qubit); now Alice and Bob may be causally separated, and Alice and Bob can only locally act on their respective qubits.